# WinForms: How to execute code AFTER my form loads?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, validation, data-binding

I have a form that I use to update Vendor info in a SQLExpress datatable via a bound BrightIdeasSoftware DataListView (a wrapper around a .Net ListView control). I would like to have it work 2 ways: with standard, non-parameterized instantiation, or with a Vendor Code passed as a parameter.

Everything works well with the standard method: the data loads from the source and processing occurs normally. My problem occurs when I try to add a new item to the binding source programmatically in the form's initialization (via BindingSource.AddNew()), because I have non-nullable columns in the datasource.

Note that the AddNew() method is not the culprit, because it works fine once the form is active (subsequent processing checks the non-nullable columns for a value before my planned EndUpdate() occurs). But there is some automatic validation performed after the form's OnLoad method has completed that forces an EndUpdate() on the binding source, and I can't find a way to invoke my AddNew() after that validation.

Here is the applicable code:

```
    Public Class VendorMaint

      Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
      End Sub

      Public Sub New(code As String, Optional bindingNavigatorVisible As Boolean = False,
       Optional selectionPanelVisible As Boolean = False)
        Me.New()
        Me.BindingNavigatorVisible = bindingNavigatorVisible
        Me.SelectionPanelVisible = selectionPanelVisible
        _HoldInitialVendorCode = code.ToUpper
      End Sub
      Private _HoldInitialVendorCode As String = Nothing

      Public Property BindingNavigatorVisible As Boolean
        Get...
        Set...
      End Property

      Public Property SelectionPanelVisible As Boolean
        Get...
        Set...
      End Property

      Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        Me.VendorTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InventoryDataSet.Vendor)
      End Sub

      Private Sub DoThisAfterValidation()
        If _HoldInitialVendorCode Is Nothing Then
          Me.DataListView1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Else
          Try
            With Me.DataListView1
              .SelectedItem = (From item In .Items.OfType(Of BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListItem)() _
               Where (item.SubItems(Me.VendorCodeColumn.Index).Text = _HoldInitialVendorCode) Select item).ToList(0)
            End With
          Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Me.VendorBindingSource.AddNew()
            Me.CodeTextBox.Text = _HoldInitialVendorCode
          End Try
        End If
      End Sub

      Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.VendorBindingSource.AddNew()
      End Sub

    End Class
```

DoThisAfterValidation() checks to see if a code was passed to the form; if not, it sets the DataListView's SelectedIndex to 0 and drops through. If a value was given, the method checks to see if the code already exists and sets the selected item there (via LINQ). So far, so good...

But if the code was passed and does NOT exist, an exception is thrown and caught, and the AddNew() method executes. This is all well and good if done once the form is active (I use active to mean *in use*, not as a reference to its Activated event). For example, if I click on Button1 a new item is created and my fields show empty as expected. So I have determined that the form's initialization is causing my problem (as shown in the stack trace below):

```
NoNullAllowedException was unhandled: Column 'Name' does not allow nulls.

   at System.Data.DataColumn.CheckNullable(DataRow row)
   at System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)
   at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
   at System.Data.DataTable.InsertRow(DataRow row, Int64 proposedID, Int32 pos, Boolean fireEvent)
   at System.Data.DataView.FinishAddNew(Boolean success)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(Int32 newPosition, Boolean validating, Boolean endCurrentEdit, Boolean firePositionChange, Boolean pullData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position(Int32 value)
   at BrightIdeasSoftware.DataSourceAdapter.HandleListViewSelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
   at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.HandleApplicationIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at InventoryManager.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I have searched the web and found suggestions such as doing my thing in the form's OnShown() method, which occurs after OnLoad(), but that doesn't get me past the validation point. I tried using an asynchronous call via BeginInvoke and a delegate, but that didn't work (yes, as you can see I was showing a MsgBox that could have interfered with the message queuing, but I commented that out and still no joy).

Also: although the DataListView (aka ObjectListView) is open-sourced, I do not have the proper VS.Net components to edit/compile CSharp code, so I cannot change the control's processing internally (I wish I could!). And I know that I could pass all of the required values as parameters, but that kind of defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do here (which is to have the user input this data).

Any ideas? I thank you in advance for your assistance!

P.S. - Although this is off-topic, I realize that using the Try...Catch block is probably not the best practice for finding out if the code is already defined; if anyone has an effective alternative, I would like to learn it. Thanks!

Comment: According to the Lifecycle of a `Form` you might want to use the `Form.Shown` event [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)

Comment: It is just not a very good control, it does very risky things in the Application.Idle event.  Not a bright idea, there just is no way that you can easily catch any exception that it causes and the event fires at very unpredictable times.  Beyond just ditching the control because it is a pita, only other thing you could do I suppose is to ensure non-nullable columns always have valid data.

Comment: Thanks @3vts, but as I mentioned above:
I have searched the web and found suggestions such as doing my thing in the form's OnShown() method, which occurs after OnLoad(), but that doesn't get me past the validation point.

Comment: @HansPassant, I value your opinions as I have seen (and used) many of your suggestions from other topics. But the control is actually quite comprehensive and maleable to a multitude of formats and uses (albeit that this situation is a pita). Is there no message I can hook or any type of indicator that I can handle that says "this form is now active (in the way that I meant _active_ above)"?

Comment: In your `Form.Shown` handler, try calling `Application.DoEvents()` first to ensure that everything else has processed. As a last resort you could also try calling `DataListView.Update()` to ensure the control has been fully painted.

Comment: `"if the code was passed and does NOT exist, an exception is thrown and caught"` - Does the Linq query itself (the part before `.ToList(0)`) cause the exception or is the `.ToList(0)'?  I suspect the latter and using a Try-Catch to detect that a query yielded zero records is bad form. Instead of `.ToList(0)` use `.FirstOrDefault` and assign it to a variable.  You can then check that variable to see if it is Nothing.